# How should I pass a reference of an object to a controller in MVC?

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, mvp

I'm trying to get better at using MVC/MVP style patterns with my WinForm apps and I'm struggling with something that maybe someone here with more experience can help me with.

Below is my basic project layout:
[image]

The class `G2.cs` handles the running of various threads and includes a Start/Stop and other various methods involved with those threads.  It is my "main" class I suppose.  It contains the main loop for my application as well.

My GUI is composed of 3 forms so far and an associated controller for each.  The `MainForm` has Start/Stop buttons that need to call methods on my `G2` class as well as possible future forms.

**What would be the correct way to pass a reference of my G2 class to all the view's controllers who need it?**  Do I need to pass the `G2` reference to the Form when I create it and the form in-turn passes it to my Controllers or... is that not a good way to handle things?

Also, am I correct in that it is the Views responsibility to create an instance of it's controller and it "owns" the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If G2 is main program class, and exists only in one instance, I would use singleton pattern on this class - no need to passing references.